# Android trouble running sample programs

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

While trying to run / create existing sample applications(eg: API Demos) provided by android SDK .... i get an error : Could not write file (x86)/.. Access denied... How can i fix this issue>>???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 ?
Maybe you don't have enough rights to access C:\Program Files (x86).

Try to be administrator.

Comment: hmmm...having troubling doing...for time being..i copied the projects to another folder and am running them....manually..."Create project from exisiting source" option...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the sdk in the Progam Files folder? Make sure you don't have any spaces in the foldername. I.e. put it to c:\android\sdk\

Comment: hmmmm....cant find anything wrong in the path such as empty spaces or anything..guess its the permissions...admin...